# matlab Gaussian integral

Tags: matlab, math, gaussian, numerical-integration

In order to calculate integral with Gauss formula and Error value, I wrote this program in matlab:

```
%calculate integral with Gauss 3-point 
clc 
syms x ;
f=input('f(x)  : ');
a=input('a = : ');
b=input('b = : ');
x=.5*((b-a)*(-1*(3/5)^0.5)+(a+b));
w0f0=(5/9)*eval(f);
x=.5*((b-a)*0+(a+b));
w1f1=(8/9)*eval(f);
x=.5*((b-a)*((.6)^.5)+(a+b));
w2f2=(5/9)*eval(f);
antegral=w0f0+w1f1+w2f2;
antegral=0.5*(b-a)*antegral;
disp(antegral)

%cal Error value  = maximum of f^(6)/1570
syms x
m6=diff(f,6);
m6
m6=-1*m6;
[x,fval]=fminbnd(fun,x0,xn);
En=fval/15750;
disp (En);
```

this code get F(x) from command line and calculate integral.

I have 2 problem:

1. If you enter f(x)=`sin(x)` ,a=0 , b=pi in command line for calculating, might see like `2.97708877614822e-009`. I want to be as just number format
2. calculating `E(n)` for some `f(x)` such as `(1+x)^3` that a=0 , b=2  have an error that it must be calculated `0` but calculate `2.97708877614822e-009`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by one, but if you want to see the result in a more readable format you can try `disp(num2str(sin(x),'%-04.3d'))` or change the format string to your taste.

Comment: @Ali i mean that for integral sin(x) that a=0 b=pi i want see for example 1.43434234 not for example 2.97708877614822e-009

Comment: You can't expect us to do the homework, you need to go through the code and ask constructive, precise questions.

Comment: It seems odd that both input functions give you `2.97708877614822e-009` (which is very close to 0, by the way). Are you sure your algorithm is working at all?

Comment: @aganders3 : what is format of '2.97708877614822e-009'?! what is e in it?

Comment: @riporter It's [`scientific notation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) and in this case it means (approximately) `2.977 * 10^-9` or `0.000000002977`.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about computer precision.

For instance, you can check that:

http://sebsauvage.net/python/snyppets/#binary_repr